# How to control the transform distance with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, css-transforms, keyframe

I made this
http://codepen.io/adamchenwei/pen/dOvJNX

and I try to apply a certain way of moving for a dom so it move for a fixed distance and stop, instead of animate and move through the whole width of the dom. However, I don't really want to fix the distance inside the css `keyframe` because I need to detect that distance dynamically, since my div that got animated ideally will change the width dynamically as well since that is not going always be 100% or any specific `px` fixed.

Is there way I can do that in JavaScript instead and not let css to take charge in this transform distance part?
Cross browser capacity will be great.

SCSS

```
.myItem {
  height: 100px;
  width: 501px;
  background-color: beige;
  animation: to-left-transition 300ms;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}


@keyframes to-left-transition {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(100%);
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="myItem">
  stuff here

</div>
```

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan thanks done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out a better way. Soooooo much easier!
I should have been using `transition` instead of animation. As that give me the flexibility to adjust the animation accordingly.

Hope it helps someone else to save couple hours!

http://codepen.io/adamchenwei/pen/xRqYNj

HTML

```
<div class="myItem">
  stuff here

</div>
```

CSS

```
.myItem {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 501px;
  background-color: beige;
  transition: transform 1s;  
}
```

JS

```
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('myItem')[0].style.transform="translateX(400px)";
  console.log('ran');
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Below is a method sugguested by [Dennis Traub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474430/change-css-class-properties-with-jquery)

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('ran');
  $("head").append('<style type="text/css"></style>');
var new_stylesheet = $("head").children(':last');
new_stylesheet.html('.myItem{animation: to-left-transition 600ms;}');
}, 3000);
```

```css
.myItem {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 501px;
  background-color: beige;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}


@keyframes to-left-transition {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item" class="myItem">
  stuff here
  
</div>
```

---

**Answer Before EDIT**
Here is a good reference for something similar to what i think you are trying to accomplish. 
Based on your dynamic input you could have a function that controls how far the div transitions. Still use your code for transition in the css, but compute how far you want in the jquery or JavaScript. Then call the css transition for how far or long you want to transition.

```js
var boxOne = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0],
    $boxTwo = $('.box:eq(1)');

document.getElementsByClassName('toggleButton')[0].onclick = function() {
  if(this.innerHTML === 'Play') 
  { 
    this.innerHTML = 'Pause';
    boxOne.classList.add('horizTranslate');
  } else {
    this.innerHTML = 'Play';
    var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(boxOne),
        marginLeft = computedStyle.getPropertyValue('margin-left');
    boxOne.style.marginLeft = marginLeft;
    boxOne.classList.remove('horizTranslate');    
  }  
}

$('.toggleButton:eq(1)').on('click', function() { 
  if($(this).html() === 'Play') 
  {
    $(this).html('Pause');
    $boxTwo.addClass('horizTranslate');
  } else {
    $(this).html('Play');
    var computedStyle = $boxTwo.css('margin-left');
    $boxTwo.removeClass('horizTranslate');
    $boxTwo.css('margin-left', computedStyle);
  }  
});
```

```css
.box {
  margin: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.box.horizTranslate {
  -webkit-transition: 3s;
  -moz-transition: 3s;
  -ms-transition: 3s;
  -o-transition: 3s;
  transition: 3s;
  margin-left: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Pure Javascript</h3>
<div class='box'></div> 
<button class='toggleButton' value='play'>Play</button>

<h3>jQuery</h3>
<div class='box'></div> 
<button class='toggleButton' value='play'>Play</button>
```

This code was written by Zach Saucier on [codepen](http://codepen.io/Zeaklous/pen/GokAm)

This is a good reference for manipulating css with JS: https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/

Comment: I checked it out previously and its one came up top on search. this will not allow me to stop in specific distance though, since it involve mannual start and pause. I want to set a distance instead of having to watch for its movement.

Comment: @Ezeewei use the .css("propertyname","value") on your jquery. You could set the margin-left or margin-right px or % with this property.

Comment: @Ezeewei For example $boxTwo.css('margin-left', DynamicVar); DynamicVar would be how ever many pixels or % you wanted.

Comment: never knew that animation can be triggered just by property change? I though it has to be triggered by transform, no?

Comment: You change the property first. To how far you want it move. Then call your transform. Does that make sense?

Comment: I did a trial run, did not work, it just jumped to the next position http://codepen.io/adamchenwei/pen/dOvJNX

Comment: @Ezeewei I edited my answer. That method moves the div when you call the function. Is close to what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: not really, but your answer got me second think about if I should be using animation ha! thanks

Comment: @Ezeewei Awesome.. Yeah in my first answer that i suggested it was using transition instead of animation. Sorry i should have mentioned that.