# modify class that isn't assigned to any element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a class, lets call it `.zero`.

I would like to access it and assign `transform:translateY(calculatedValueHere);`

That will trigger an animation. Basically I need to perform some calculations on css translateY and then apply that value to the object I want to animate.

How can I do that using javascript or jquery?

EDIT: jquery or javascript methods for animation (animate method for example) are not an option, because of performance issues. css translate uses GPU acceleration, and that is what I am after.

Comment: First of all, sample code, then check [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: I don't want animate, because my animation is too complex to be handled by jquery or javascript. I am not getting the performance I need. Css translate on the other hand uses GPU acceleration

Comment: Why didn't you mention that? Be specific!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change CSS class properties with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474430/change-css-class-properties-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to dynamically change the css property of a class. Thay way any element you add the class to in the future will have the same behaviour as well.

The Stack overflow answer to the question below discusses how to accomplish that.

[Change CSS class properties with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11474522/2049132)

I'd mark this question as a duplicate/similar to the link above but i'm way under the reputations i need for it.

Answer (score 1):

Just apply styles to that class in your css, e.g.

```
.zero { 
    / *your animations */ 
}
```

Then you can use, say jQuery to add the class to your desired element. The animation will not start until the class has been added.

```
$('yourElm').addClass('zero');
```

Comment: This doesn't handle the main part of the question that asks about having a calculated value in the style: `transform:translateY(calculatedValueHere);`.

Comment: What are you using to calculate the value? What value are you trying to calculate exactly?

Comment: Some complex stuff. 10 different widths and heights in equation I used user2049132 answer and it is a nice workaround