# Microsoft Dynamics 365 Change Header Color on Form based on value

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

I have an option set on my Account / Sales form.  Based on this value I want to change the header color at the top of the form.

I can do this manually through editing the CSS through the Developer Tools, however when I try and do this through Form Properties and Web Resources I cannot get the color to change.

As a base test I'm just trying to inject the CSS into the page through javascript.

Here is the CSS web resource that I created.

```
.ms-crm-Form-HeaderPosition {
    background-color: rgba(2,206,239,1) !important;
}
```

Here is the javascript web resource I created:

```
function load_css_file(filename){ 
   var fileref = document.createElement("link") 
   fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet") 
   fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css") 
   fileref.setAttribute("href", filename) 
   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref) 
}
function myFormOnLoad(){ 
   load_css_file('/WebResources/aws_ColoredHeaderMGA.css'); 
}
```

I then went to my Sales form, changed the form properties to load in my Javascript web resource and then told it to call the function `myFormOnLoad` as on `OnLoad` even for the form.

I'm not getting any errors, I know the javascript is getting called because I added an `alert` to it just to make sure and I did receive the alert.

What am I missing to get the header color to change?

[image: jquery attempt]

Comment: Have you considered (or tried) [to modify the style class itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11474430/205233) instead using jquery?

Comment: @Filburt I'd have to play around with it, I'm not sure how to achieve this from within the Dynamics 365 engine.

Comment: You'd have to include your own jquery.js web resource since MS hides `$` from form scripts - the quoted solution can simply be run inside your existing `myFormOnLoad()`.

Comment: Just tried myself - adding `$('.ms-crm-Class-Name-Here').css('background-color', 'yellow');` in a function registered in OnLoad does the trick and is way easier than appending a style sheet at run time.

Comment: @Filburt Do i just add a full jquery script from like jquery.com as a web resource or is there a bit more too it?  I switched it over but am getting an error on the $ not being recognized.

Comment: Yes, simply upload the minified js from jquery as a web resource and add it as a web resource to your form ordered before your web resource js containing the OnLoad function.

Comment: @Filburt I'll have to try some more tomorrow.  I added the resource then I tried to add it to the form and it said invalid web resource type for form.  Will keep playing with it tho.

Comment: No need to upload jQuery, just use `parent.$`

Comment: @Alex I tried the parent.$ method but it gives me the same error $ is not recognized.  Added image of my attempt.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is looking for working code, the below one we are using.

I guess the URL is the problem in OP. Add OrgName & remove extension (.css)

```
function LdCSS() {
    var path = "/orgname/WebResources/new_custom";
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = path;
    link.media = 'all';
    head.appendChild(link);
}
```

Comment: Is this with the newest version of Microsoft Dynamics 365, I was unable to get this to work as well.  Thos no errors from what I can tell upon examining the header it doesn't look like my header is being appended.

Comment: It seemed to work the first time I tried it (I think), but within a few minutes, It is not working any more for me (using D365 v9). Is it possible that MS has somehow managed to build a barrier to prevent .appendChild() from working, or possibly an event listener that prevents changes to the Head.